# systemd mount cycle for bind mount of cifs mount

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemd-mount

I have a CIFS mount of a single volume which then has 2 subdirectories bind mounted. Upon boot, systemd complains of an "ordering cycle" and fails to mount 1 of the binds but the other works fine. If I run `mount -a`, the missing bind is mounted. I have been able to recreate this behavior in a new VM.

### /etc/fstab

```
//server.example.com    /mnt/media             cifs    [snip]  0  0
/mnt/media/secure       /var/www/media/secure  none    bind    0  0
/mnt/media/public       /var/www/media/public  none    bind    0  0
```

The bind mounts are not altered, those are the actual names. I don't know how, but, I think that may be significant, perhaps due to sort order because when I change the order in `fstab` only the `public` bind mount fails. `secure` always works.

### logs from journal

```
Mar 19 14:06:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on var-www-media-public.mount/start
Mar 19 14:06:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on mnt-media.mount/start
Mar 19 14:06:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on network-online.target/start
Mar 19 14:06:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on networking.service/start
Mar 19 14:06:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
Mar 19 14:06:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job var-www-media-public.mount/start
Mar 19 14:06:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: var-www-media-public.mount: Job var-www-media-public.mount/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with local-fs.target/start
```

I've tried specifying `x-systemd.requires=/mnt/media` on the bind mount but it made no change. I am at a loss for where to go next with this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure why even one of the bind mounts is able to work.  Here is my suggestion why both might fail together, and how to fix it:

Your `networking.service` is ordered after local filesystems.  The bind mounts are being treated as local filesystems.  But, the bind mounts are also ordered after a network mount - systemd adds these logical dependencies automatically for bind mounts.

In which case you need to tell `systemd` that the bind mount is actually a network mount.  There is an option deliberately for this sort of case.  Simply add the mount option `_netdev` to the bind mounts.  For further information, this option is defined in `man systemd.mount`.

Comment: Thank you! I've seen _netdev before but totally forgot about it. As for why one mount works... I can't figure it out either.

Comment: Important detail: it also required setting `x-systemd.requires=/mnt/media` to the mount options otherwise the bind was to the local directory later covered by the CIFS mount.

Comment: @mjb2kmn thanks!  That's odd because I saw the automatic dependency in the code.  Maybe you have an older version than I looked at.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v238/src/core/mount.c#L296

Comment: Correct, affected system has v229.

Comment: @mjb2kmn gotcha.  Looks like its a logic error for _netdev bind mounts specifically, which was fixed in v230.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/26919ac110c543291b1ad6fa6f22f56253de704d

Comment: Thank you, It was driving me crazy.